# Dropdown menu from getbootstrap.com not working?

Tags: html, css, web

For some reason the dropdown menu within the nav bar isn't working

```
"<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary", data-bs-theme ="dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Python Project</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/user">User</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="/caesar">Caesar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Types
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/caesar">Caesar</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>"
```

I've tried a few things but this code has come straight from getbootstrap.com so I'm unsure why it isn't working

Comment: Which Bootstrap version are you using? Have you correctly added the Bootstrap CSS and JS?